# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'P4'

Tags: python, perforce

I want to use python library for perforce. I have created a python script by importing P4. In order to use this, i have installed perforce-p4python3, below steps i followed,

> created a file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/perforce.list with below content

**deb http://package.perforce.com/apt/ubuntu/ bionic release**

> wget -qO - https://package.perforce.com/perforce.pubkey | sudo apt-key
> add - sudo apt-get update

> sudo apt install perforce-p4python

when i execute the python script, i am getting below error,

```
import P4
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'P4'
```

when i try to install again,

```
sudo apt install perforce-p4python3
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    perforce-p4python3 is already the newest version (2020.1-1983437~bionic).
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 100 not upgraded.
```

when i do pip freeze, i don't see p4python. Did i missed something?. How can i use P4() functionality in python?

Comment: Are you using a virtual environment?

Comment: @Chris i have mentioned the link, by following that i have installed. I am not using virtual environment. I am using base OS as Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. It is because of mismatching the python version. i executed python script using python3

```
python3 perforce_connection.py
```